# How to np.concatenate list with tensors?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pytorch, concatenation

I have a list with tensors:

```
[tensor([[0.4839, 0.3282, 0.1773,  ..., 0.2931, 1.2194, 1.3533],
        [0.4395, 0.3462, 0.1832,  ..., 0.7184, 0.4948, 0.3998]],
        device='cuda:0'),
 tensor([[1.0586, 0.2390, 0.2315,  ..., 0.9662, 0.1495, 0.7092],
        [0.6403, 0.0527, 0.1832,  ..., 0.1467, 0.8238, 0.4422]],
        device='cuda:0')]
```

I want to stack all [1xfeatures] matrices into one by np.concatenate(X). but this error appears:

```
TypeError: can't convert cuda:0 device type tensor to numpy. Use Tensor.cpu() to copy the tensor to host memory first.
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tensors are still on the GPU and numpy operations happen on CPU. You can either send both tensors back to cpu first `numpy.concatenate((a.cpu(), b.cpu())`, as the error message indicates.

Or you can avoid moving off the GPU and use a `torch.cat()`

```py
a = torch.ones((6),)
b = torch.zeros((6),)

torch.cat([a,b], dim=0)
# tensor([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
```

Answer (score 2):

The NumPy function `np.concatenate()` requires the input to be a NumPy array, but your data are contained in tensors. The error comes from the fact that the NumPy function fails when trying to convert your data to a NumPy array, which itself is due to the fact that your tensors are located on your GPU.

You may want to keep these tensors on your GPU, in which case you can use either use:

- the `torch.cat()` [function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/concat) if you're using PyTorch
- the `tf.concat()` [function](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.cat.html) if you're using TensorFlow

Alternatively, you may move the tensors to the CPU. To do that, simply add `.cpu()` to your tensors prior to using `np.concatenate()` as the error indicates.

Answer (score 1):

Numpy works on the CPU, but your tensors are on the GPU.

Use `torch.cat()` instead.